# iOS app first run user tutorial

Tags: ios, highlight

I would like to add an integrated welcome tutorial to my app that just highlights a few buttons and educate the user what some features are.  I remember seeing this I the google app. Is there a tutorial on how this is done or is it simply a video file that plays to look like the app..
 Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'd agree with James, that rather than a video, a user controlled help/tutorial is better. Let the user control the speed with which the online help progresses and/or is dismissed. Even better, I like integrating the help into the app itself, e.g. show the user help/tips when they first visits a particular screen for the first time or where they tap a little question mark button for the tips/help to pop up.

I have to confess, though, that I've shifted my thinking regarding integrated help/tips in an app and now tend to consider it a design failure. If the app is not intuitive and discoverable, then I've failed as a designer. I can easily imagine apps of sufficient complexity where online help is necessary, but before you invest time in help/tips, I'd urge you to consider a user interface redesign that obviates the need for it. Some of the best apps out there are intuitive and don't have any help screens at all.

If you to do online help, though, the common solutions are:

1. Present first time users a series of full screen help pages that they can tap through one at a time at their own pace, with heavy emphasis on visual elements rather than text description. This is the closest to your original question. You could even animate the appearance of the visual elements on this help screen if you want (to give it a bit of a video-like feel), but let the user progress to the next screen (if you need multiple screens) at their own pace. (You can do this effect by having your main view controller determine if this is the first time the user's used the app, if so, use pushViewController/presentViewController to go to the help screen (and again if there are additional help screens), and then when done, pop/dismiss back to the main view controller.)
2. The first time a user enters a particular screen, either have little pop up help/tips that show up. Optionally you could overlay this help on top of the screen itself, dimming the actual screen behind it, so the user knows that they're in a different "help mode", with little pointers or other visual indicator linking your help to certain design features on the screen behind the help screen. (You can do this by having the relevant screens keep track of whether they've been visited before, and if so, overlay the help tips, which will be dismissed when the user taps anywhere on the screen.)
3. Put a help button which will cause user help tips to popup on the screen. A good example of this approach is Apple's iPhoto for iPad, which includes not only hints/tips show up next to the various controls right there on the screen, but also with links to more substantive descriptions where needed.

To wrap up, I'd suggest (a) redesign your app so help is not necessary; but if you can't (b) pick an app that does a particularly elegant presentation of online help and see if you can reproduce that effect yourself. I don't know of any good tutorials on how to do this, but frankly none of this is terribly complicated, so you really shouldn't have much of a problem reproducing the effect you want. And if you do hit a road block, come back to SO with the specific question on how to do a particular visual effect, and I'm sure we'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could play a video that looks like the app, but that's messy and looks silly if they want to stop it as it is clearly a video. A much better way would be to create your own custom overlay views which point to different buttons and give them info. With this implementation, the user is able to "stop" the tutorial whenever they want instead of having to view a video for 40 seconds with no easy way out; also you could add an option to see the tutorial again much more easily this way.